# JPA entities in external JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

Well, I have an external JAR with `@MappedSupperClass` annotation and I'm trying to extend a class from this external JAR. See bellow:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(value = {
        @NamedQuery(name = "AgendaDentista.findByDentista", query = "SELECT c FROM AgendaDentista c "
                + "JOIN FETCH c.diaSemana "
                + "JOIN FETCH c.dentista "
                + "WHERE c.dentista.id = :idDentista"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "AgendaDentista.findByDentistaWhereDiaSemanaAndHora", query = "SELECT c FROM AgendaDentista c "
                + "JOIN FETCH c.diaSemana "
                + "JOIN FETCH c.dentista "
                + "WHERE c.dentista.id = :idDentista "
                + "AND c.diaSemana.codigo = :diaSemana "
                + "AND :hora BETWEEN c.horaInicio AND c.horaFim") })
@Table(name = "agenda_dentista")
public class AgendaDentista extends AbstractBean {
```

My `AbstractBean` class is inside another package (in external jar). But I got the following error in `@Entity` annotation:

> The entity has no primary key attribute defined

I already import the JAR in my build path and put this in Deployment Assembly (Eclipse).

I tried use jar-file in my persistence.xml but i got error: jar file cannot be resolved.

```
<persistence-unit name="odontonewPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jar-file>jwebbuild-1.0.jar</jar-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

**SOLUTION**

After a lot of search i got a solution. This appers to be a Eclipse BUG, beacuse i must put my AbstractBean class in persistence.xml and force eclipse to find it.

See:

```
<class>br.com.jwebbuild.bean.AbstractBean</class>
```

So, now eclipse stop to say that my class don't have a primary key attribute defined

Comment: Your ID in the MapperSuperClass is protected ?

Comment: Do you have field annotated with @Id? If not you have to annotate a particular field with Id

Comment: Yeah i have a field annotated with @Id and protected

Answer (score 0):

If your entities are spread over different JARs, you should look into [composite persistence units](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_composite_unit.htm) - I assume you use EclipseLink?

Comment: Ah, sorry - my mistake - you're using Hibernate, my answer isn't applicable.